# Split a numpy matrix, then rejoin after processing?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Imagine I had a 3-D matrix in numpy like this

```
(1,5) | (2,6)
------|------
(3,7) | (4,8)
```

I want it split into two 2-D matrices as follows

```
1 | 2   5 | 6
--|-- , -----
3 | 4   7 | 8
```

So the original matrix is shape (2, 2, 2), and I want it split into two matrices of size (2, 2)

Then let's say I do some processing of the individual matrices and want to join them back together from two (2, 2) matrices into one (2, 2, 2) matrix, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: What processing exactly? Good chance no splitting is needed.

Comment: my goal is to run a 2D convolution over the individual matrices. Let's say that the matrices represent X,Y components of vectors, and the vectors are arranged in a matrix. I want to run a gaussian blur over the X components individually and then over the Y components.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is indeed a need to apply a function (say, `foo()`) to each submatrix, the following code does the job:

```
result = np.stack( # Combine
                  [foo(a[:,:,i].T) # Apply
                   for i in range(a.shape[2])], # Split
                   axis=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.swapaxes` but I agree with the comment by @kabanus that depending on your goal, it may not be necessary.

```
a = np.array([1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4, 8]).reshape(2, 2, 2)

b = np.swapaxes(a, 0, 2)

for i in range(len(b)):
    print(b[i])
    b[i] = (i + 1) * b[i] # do something

c = np.swapaxes(b, 0, 2)
```

Comment: But how does one combine the results of "do something" back again?

Comment: @DyZ you make a good point. I edited my answer to address that.